# Ramda `cond` else statement

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I'm looking at the [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/0.21.0/index.html) docs for the [`cond` function](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#cond) and am confused about its behavior. The docs state that `cond`...

> Returns a function, fn, which encapsulates if/else-if/else logic.
>   R.cond takes a list of [predicate, transform] pairs. All of the
>   arguments to fn are applied to each of the predicates in turn until
>   one returns a "truthy" value, at which point fn returns the result of
>   applying its arguments to the corresponding transformer. If none of
>   the predicates matches, fn returns undefined.

Here is the example given:

```
var fn = R.cond([
  [R.equals(0),   R.always('water freezes at 0°C')],
  [R.equals(100), R.always('water boils at 100°C')],
  [R.T,           temp => 'nothing special happens at ' + temp + '°C']
]);

fn(0); //=> 'water freezes at 0°C'
fn(50); //=> 'nothing special happens at 50°C'
fn(100); //=> 'water boils at 100°C'
```

I understand the `[predicate, transform]` aspect of the function, but it isn't clear to me how the "else" portion works. In a typical if/else-if/else statement, the "else" portion does not accept a predicate. In the example, however, each of the arrays have a predicate. Maybe knowing how `R.T` operates in this case would help, but searching for `T` in the docs was fruitless.

*How can I use Ramda's `cond` function to capture conditional "else" functionality in order to return a default value?*

Comment: `R.T` is a function that always returns `true`, so for `R.cond` it's basically equal to `default` in typical switch clause (of imperative languages).

Comment: Perhaps looking at [the implementation](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/master/src/cond.js) helps, it is quite small.

Comment: This might make it more clear: http://ramdajs.com/0.21.0/docs/#T.  The else case you see there is just another case statement.  It's the predicate, and the fact that it's in the last position, that makes it act like a default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`R.T` always returns `true` and ignores any parameters passed to it.
That is the reason the `100` you passed in was ignored and it just returned `true`.

`R.cond` searches each of the `[predicate, transform]` pairs, and stops searching on the first predicate that evaluates to `true`.
So the first matching entity from the `[predicate, transform]` pair would be evaluated.

If nothing is `true`, then it reaches the end and executes the `R.T` predicate (which is always `true`) and that acts like the else part of list.